# retrieving return value from oracle execute method

Tags: java, oracle, jakarta-ee, stored-procedures, jdbc

I read about differences between execute and executeQuery methods in Oracle and saw to text below

> executeQuery() — This is used generally for reading the content of the
>   database. The output will be in the form of ResultSet. Generally
>   SELECT statement is used.
>
> execute() — If you dont know which method to be used for executing SQL
>   statements, this method can be used. This will return a boolean. TRUE
>   **indicates the result is a ResultSet** and FALSE indicates it has the int value which denotes number of rows affected by the query.

Here is the my question. I execute a procedure with a execute method but it only returns an integer value. I retrieve the return value like this:

```
stmt.execute(); 
output = stmt.getInteger(1);
close(stmt);               // statement
close(connection);         // connection
```

I do not use a ResultSet object here and therefore I do not close explicitly anything like ResultSet. So according to text above, if execute function returns a resultset, what happens to that resultset in my code? Does it stay opened? If it is, how can I close it on that way?

Answer (score 0):

[`CallableStatement.getInt()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/CallableStatement.html#getInt-int-) doesn't relate to a `ResultSet`, it relates to an output parameter of a stored procedure. If your stored procedure returns a cursor, then you'd have to use `getResultSet()` and process the results from there.

With regard to closing - closing a `Statement` does not mandate that all the `ResultSet`s based on it are also closed, and IIRC, with Oracle JDBC drivers, a `ResultSet` may indeed remain open after the `Statement` is closed. Hence, you'd have to explicitly close it if it exists.